# SqlTableDependency .Net 7 start pefectly on debug IIS Express but error in publish IIS

Tags: c#, sql-server, iis, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-7.0

i have an issue that my SqlTableDependency successfully start on debug with IIS Express but error in Published code in IIS.

below is my code

```
private SqlTableDependency<WfeVendorChats> _tableDependency;

        private void StartSqlTableDependency()
        {
            var connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionApp");
            Log.Information("StartSqlTableDependency. connection = " + connectionString);
            var tableName = "wfe_vendor_chats"; // Set the table name

            try
            {
                Log.Information("_tableDependency connectionString " + connectionString);
                Log.Information("_tableDependency tableName " + tableName);
                _tableDependency = new SqlTableDependency<WfeVendorChats>(connectionString, tableName);
                _tableDependency.OnChanged += (sender, e) => Dependency_OnChanged(sender, e);
                _tableDependency.Start();
                Log.Information("_tableDependency start");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error("_tableDependency error. Reason: " + ex.Message);
                Log.Error("Exception Type: " + ex.GetType().FullName);
                Log.Error("Stack Trace: " + ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
```

this is the error detail. i'm using serilog for this

```
{"Timestamp":"2023-08-07T00:12:38.5445741+07:00","Level":"Error","MessageTemplate":"_tableDependency error. Reason: The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser' threw an exception.","Properties":{"TransportConnectionId":"iDxQPLk4t9T8j8sa0PWFcg","RequestId":"800032df-0000-d000-b63f-84710c7967bb","RequestPath":"/chatHub"}}
```

it seems the connection to SQL Server is failed. i already install SQL Server Native Client on my Windows Server. but still can't figure it out why my connection failed after publish.

any advice will be helpful. Thanks. Best Regrads

Comment: Is there some reason you are using `System.Data.SqlClient` instead of `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` namespace objects?

Comment: @DanGuzman i'm using TableDependency.SqlClient, cause i want to track changing record on my specific table wfe_vendor_chat

Comment: Have you checked the SQL connection string? Make sure you are using the correct connection string in the code you posted. Also, check that the IIS application pool running the published application has the required permissions to access the SQL Server database.

Comment: @YurongDai the connection is correct, in debug is working perfectly. but after publish it doesn't work

Comment: Make sure your publishing environment has the correct network access and firewall settings to connect to SQL Server. Because the firewall might block the connection, and the network configuration might be different between the development environment and the production server. Also, check the event log on the production server for any additional information about the error.